# Яндекс.Карты API. Программный выбор фильтра

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Пример работы с фильтрами из яндекса https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter

https://jsfiddle.net/ABerezin/rw960xqz/1/

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: []
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 64,
            // Макет метки кластера pieChart.
            clusterIconLayout: "default#pieChart"
        });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    // Создадим 5 пунктов выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems = ['Школа', 'Аптека', 'Магазин', 'Больница', 'Бар']
        .map(function(title) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: title
                },
                state: {
                    selected: false
                }
            })
        }),
        // Теперь создадим список, содержащий 5 пунктов.
        listBoxControl = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Фильтр',
                title: 'Фильтр'
            },
            items: listBoxItems,
            state: {
                // Признак, развернут ли список.
                expanded: false,
                filters: listBoxItems.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                    filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                    return filters;
                }, {})
            }
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl);

    // Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка.
    listBoxControl.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
        var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
        var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, listBoxControl.state.get('filters'));
        filters[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
        listBoxControl.state.set('filters', filters);
    });

    var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(listBoxControl.state);
    filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
        // Применим фильтр.
        objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
    });

    function getFilterFunction(categories){
        return function(obj){
            var content = obj.properties.balloonContent;
            return categories[content]
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/object_manager_filter/data.json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });

}
```

Как программно выбрать фильтр, например сделать активным фильтр 'Бар'?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться методом select() https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.ListBoxItem-docpage/ :

```
listBoxControl.get(4).select();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/79qfgxvm/

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо!меню 
Добавил раскрытие списка после выбора.
    listBoxControl.state.set('expanded', true);

https://jsfiddle.net/ABerezin/rw960xqz/3/